# My Samsung laptop will not enter boot menu

Tags: windows

A can't get my samsung laptop to go into the boot menu. I have tried f2, esc, f10.
FN+f2...nothing opens the boot menu.
I even tried plugging in a keyboard. Still no luck. 
I put a recovery disk in...still no luck
the laptop goes into "preparing automatic repair" then the screen goes black.

Comment: Need more details as to which point of the boot process are we seeing the loop. Are we in the BIOS boot section or after MBR boot?

Answer (score 0):

The assumption here is that you are running a Microsoft Windows OS. You press F8 just as you see your system post message. This should give you the boot menu. Good luck with the recovery.

Comment: Yes. windows 8 OS.....F8 did not work either